# deploy an AWS workload through website

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am new to AWS so forgive me if there is an easy answer. I was wondering if there is a way to create a website (I have all of the html for it) that can deploy a certain workload (Apache, Core OS, etc) specified by a user through cloudformation after hitting a certain button?

Comment: please share what you have done so far. your codes, errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** AWS CloudFormation can automate the deployment of AWS services including Amazon EC2 instances.

To configure a server with your desired software configuration, you could either:

- Create a fully-configured disk image with all the software you desire, then [create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) and launch future EC2 instances using that disk image, **or**
- Launch an EC2 instance with the base operating system, but [pass a User Data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html); the script is executed when the instance launches and can be used to install the desired software.

For example, this script will install Apache and PHP, download some web files and serve them through the web server:

```
#!/bin/sh
yum -y install httpd php
chkconfig httpd on
/etc/init.d/httpd start
cd /var/www/html
wget http://my-bucket/my-files.zip
unzip my-files.zip
```

As for "hitting a button", you could deploy the instance in several ways:

- Via a CloudFormation from the CloudFormation console
- Via a CloudFormation template from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`create-stack` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html)
- Via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`run-instances` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) passing in the User Data script